# my sphinx offline Speech recognition is not working accurately

Tags: python, android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-assistant

I am using sphinx pocket offline speech recognition module for creating google like assistant using python but for some reason it doesn't work accurately, even if i speak hello into mic it is unable recognize that. please provide solution.

below code is what my program looks like:

```
import webbrowser
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3

engine = pyttsx3.init()
voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
engine.setProperty('voice', 'voices[1].id')

reco = sr.Recognizer()
def sphinxCall(f_audio):
    try:
        print("Listening...")
        statement = reco.recognize_sphinx(f_audio)
        print(statement)
        if statement == "open browser":
            webbrowser.open('http://www.google.com/')
            pyttsx3.speak("opening browser")
    
    except:
        print("Try again")
    
    
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    reco.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = reco.listen(source)
    sphinxCall(audio)
```

sphinx speech recognition is not detecting a very simple speech. i Dont have  an idea if error is in my code or in module sphinx pocket speech recognition. Please help.

Comment: Please provide more context: what have you tried, what is your code, you audio settings... Please (re)check the stackoverflow HOWTO post question

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.